# Is it good practice to call a form inside a controller?

Tags: forms, 9

I have a list which needs to be displayed and filtered and sorted using filters and sort drop-down. I also need to add a pagination. I also have a map integrated to the page which will change based on the results.

Is it advisable to directly use the *_form* parameter in routing.yml file and attach to a `FormBase` or create a controller and call the form within the controller?

Comment: I would say: it is advisable to directly use _form, because of caching. If you have a form inside a controller, it is possible the controller will be uncacheable because of the form.

Answer (score 7):

The `_form` parameter is converted to a `_controller` parameter pointing at a core form controller. So technically it doesn't matter whether you use the core controller or a custom controller. If you use a custom controller you probably want to return not only the form but also additional content. Then place the entire form array as a sub-key in the controller render array without rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a controller to show a form via the [*form_builder*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/form_builder/9.3.x) service. That's what Drupal core does too, but only to show a form inside a page that contains more than the form, for example in the `SystemController` class and its [`SystemController::themesPage()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Controller%21SystemController.php/function/SystemController%3A%3AthemesPage/9.3.x).

```php
  $build = [];
  $build[] = [
    '#theme' => 'system_themes_page',
    '#theme_groups' => $theme_groups,
    '#theme_group_titles' => $theme_group_titles,
  ];
  $build[] = $this->formBuilder
    ->getForm('Drupal\\system\\Form\\ThemeAdminForm', $admin_theme_options);
  return $build;
```

Routes showing a single form, whose class is set with the *_form* property, are really using a controller ([`HtmlFormController`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21HtmlFormController.php/class/HtmlFormController/9.3.x)) Drupal sets for them, which just builds the form with the *form_builder* service.
Instead of implementing a controller to render a single form with the same service, and use it for a route used in my module, I would rather set the form to show with *_form* and let the Drupal controller render the form.